# Rules for creating new Warlock invocations

Tags: dnd-3.5e, eldritch-invocations

I see that there is only a post on the website with rules for creating a new spell ([Rules for creating new spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3515/rules-for-creating-new-spells)), and I have a similar question:

How can I create a new (normal, non-epic) invocation? Is there a good source for advice on that?

For example, I know that a wizard can research and create new spells, but what if a warlock improvises and tries to create a new invocation?